# Sort keys and Sum their values in bash

Tags: bash, awk

I have a list of strings (stdin) like next:

```
1 pineapples
28 apples
16 oranges
8 apples
2 apples
2 oranges
56 pineapples
```

Is there a native way (like `sort` & `uniq -c`) with which I can merge and sum them like this:

```
38 apples
18 oranges
57 pineapples
```

like `sort |uniq -c` do, but not only for occurrences number?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try this one:

```
awk '{a[$2] += $1} END{for (i in a) print a[i], i}' < in.txt
```

The output

```
38 apples
57 pineapples
18 oranges
```

Comment: When awk is the right tool for the job, it's really the right tool for the job.

Comment: Love awk, though don't know it well, just was sure it would fit here, so put the right tag :)

Comment: This is elegant, but note the output is *not sorted*. It's not clear from the question if that is an actual requirement, but just something to be aware of. As a side note, GNU `awk` *can* traverse arrays in for loops in a defined (sorted) manner, controlled via `PROCINFO["sorted_in"]` (in this case, one would set: `PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@val_str_asc"`).

Comment: works flawless, I had troubles with datamash. awk is slower but did the job fine

Answer (score 4):

With [GNU `datamash`](https://www.gnu.org/software/datamash/):

```
$ <file datamash -Wst' ' -g2 sum 1
apples 38
oranges 18
pineapples 57
```

(`-W` use whitespace for input field delimiters, `-t' '` use a space for output field delimiter, `-s` sort input, `-g2` group by column 2, `sum 1` sum values from column 1 in each group.)

Not a big winner here (over `awk`), but it really shines on a bit more complex statistical operations (e.g. calculating group median, variance, skewness, etc.).

To get the format as given in question (if that matters), we need to reverse the order of output fields manually because `datamash` always outputs grouped-by columns first:

```
$ <file datamash -Wst' ' -g2 sum 1 | datamash -Wt' ' reverse
38 apples
18 oranges
57 pineapples
```

Answer (score 0):

Awk is the right tool for this job. However here is an alternative version with bash [associative arrays](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Arrays.html) for those not familiar with awk and who has bash version >= 4.0. This reads each line of the file Fruits and stores the numbers using the second column as key.

```
declare -A Sumarray
while IFS=" " read num thing
do
  if [[ -v Sumarray[$thing] ]]
  then
     Sumarray[$thing]=$(( ${Sumarray[$thing]} + $num ))
  else
     Sumarray[$thing]=$num
  fi
done < Fruits

$ for K in "${!Sumarray[@]}"; do echo ${Sumarray[$K]} $K ; done
38 apples
57 pineapples
18 oranges
```

Comment: Those not familiar with awk should learn awk so they can do things like this easily, efficiently, portably, robustly, etc.. A shell is for manipulating files and processes, for manipulating text you should use the tool that the guys who invented shell invented to manipulate text - awk..

Answer (score 0):

Summing values and **sorting** the output using `awk`:

```
awk '{  
   items[$2]+=$1 
} 
END { 
   asorti(items, sorted)
   for(i in sorted) 
      print items[sorted[i]] " " sorted[i] 
}' input_file
```

Using only `bash`:

```
declare -A items=()

while read -r num item; do
   ((items[$item] += num))
done < input_file

sorted=()
while IFS= read -r -d '' item; do
   sorted+=("$item")
done < <(printf '%s\0' "${!items[@]}" | sort -z) 

for index in "${sorted[@]}"; do
  echo "${items[$index]} $index"
done
```